# Expected declaration error for making high score

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to make a little game, now I want to make it possible to see the high score of the game. At the first `UIViewController` (viewcontroller1) you can see the score (`UILabel` called ourScore) and the score is working with (`var score: String!`). The score has been connected to a label called recentScore at the other `UIViewController` (viewcontroller2) With the use of

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") {
            var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as! PointsViewController;
       }
}
```

the score will connect to the other label at the other `UIViewController` (2) to see the final score. Now I wanted to make it possible to see also the high score. Currently the high score is with in the code the following on the first `UIViewController`

```
let highscore = ourScore.text;
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(highscore, forKey: "Highscore")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

and at the other `UIViewController` it is:

```
highSchore.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Highscore")
```

highScore is currently the label in the second `UIViewController` where the high score should be showing, I got an error at the code

```
highSchore.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Highscore")
```

In the above line, it says **Expected declaration**.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because you have the code in the wrong place in the class so move it to any function or in `viewDidLoad` method.

You can have only declarations in class scope, not expressions to be executed.

And it will work fine.

**EDIT:**
In your second `UIViewController` just read highScore from `NSUserDefaults` this way:

```
let hScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Highscore") as! String
highSchoreLabel.text = hScore
```

Comment: Thank you, I do not get any more an error. But I think I got something wrong wit naming the labels, by let highscore = ourScore.text; ourScore is the label where the points are counted at the first UIViewController, is this good? and by highScore.text = NSUserDefaults... highScore is the label with the highscore in the other label is this also good? The reason why is because the high score in the app stays at zero, like the labels says in storyboard.

Comment: Looks like theres only problem: highScore.text = highScore gives an error: "'String' does not have a member named 'text'

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's not the answer, cause the error gives the error for .text so not highScore. It is a label

Comment: Feel free to ask another question with more detail..:)

Comment: So I changed it a little bit to highScore.text = highscore it gives no errors. But when I do start the app the highscore stays at 0. The label of the highscore is highScore and in the code its: @IBOutlet var highScore: UILabel!

Comment: But that is not same as what you asked in your question. And that error is solved now so you can accept answer..:)

Comment: And for your new error you can solve it easily by reading some documentation.

Answer (score 3):

To be clear for rookies like me, you can get the expected declaration error when you try to use a variable in your ViewController **not** in a function.

For example this code will give you the expected declaration error.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var savedText = ""
    savedText = "this" //<- Expected declaration error
```

While this code will not give you the error.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var savedText = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        savedText = "this" //<- No error here because you used it in a function
```