# swift compiler shows Expected declaration error?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When this code is written in `AllListViewController` and run, the compiler shows the Expected Declaration error:

```
for list in lists{
    let item = ChecklistItems()
    item.text = "Item for \(list.name))"
    list.items.append(item)
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you asking (i don't understand your question/problem)?

Comment: actually the code is :

Comment: for list in lists {
let item = ChecklistItem() item.text = "Item for \(list.name)" list.items.append(item)
}

Comment: i edited yoru question, it will probably soon contian the new code, but please be more precise abotu what you are asking. also, maybe consider using the SO version in your native language (there are sister sites for many languages).

Comment: Please post the actual error your are getting, or better still a screenshot.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I think you have the code in the wrong place in the class same like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872657/expected-declaration-error-for-making-high-score/31873051?noredirect=1#comment51664944_31873051) question.

so move it to any function or in `viewDidLoad` method.

Hope it will help.

Comment: nice guess. totally didn't see the class

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 16):

You have the code like below image:

[image]
Seems like Your code is outside the function. If `allListViewController` is your `UIViewController` class where the `for` loop code is written make sure the code should be inside the body of any function of `allListViewController` class. It can not be outside.

**Example:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    for list in lists{
        let item = ChecklistItems()
        item.text = "Item for (list.name))"
        list.items.append(item)
    }
}
```

You can just **initialise/declare** the variables **(will be global variables)** outside the function body.

Answer (score 1):

When we add code which should be added inside some function and then call , At that time it will show **error: expected declaration**

Because only Property Declaration should come directly inside class .
So when we use any property then it should happen in some function .

Here is an example of Activity Indicator class I have created.

**Error when code is written outside.**
[image]

**It will work when written inside function.**
[image]