# Randomly select 5 elements from an array list without repeating an element

Tags: arrays, swift, random, swift3

I am currently trying to make an app for iOS but I can't get some simple code down. Basically I need to randomly select 5 elements from an array list without repeating an element. I have a rough draft, but it only displays one element.

Here is my code:

```
let array1 = ["salmon", "turkey", "salad", "curry", "sushi", "pizza"]

let randomIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array1.count)))

print(array1[randomIndex1])
```

Comment: thats because you are only getting 1 unique index from that array.

Comment: im sorry, i am very new to swift. How would i fix that? if i tell it to print again i could get a repeat answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
let array1 = ["salmon", "turkey", "salad", "curry", "sushi", "pizza", "curry", "sushi", "pizza"]
var resultSet = Set<String>()

while resultSet.count < 5 {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array1.count)))
    resultSet.insert(array1[randomIndex])
}

let resultArray = Array(resultSet)

print(resultArray)
```

A `set` can contain unique elements only, so it can't have the same element more than once.

I created an empty `set`, then as long as the array contains less than 5 elements (the number you chose), I iterated and added a random element to the `set`.

In the last step, we need to convert the set to an array to get the array that you want.

Comment: Dude this is awesome, thanks so much for the explanation! I didn't even know sets existed haha.

Comment: An element may be chosen more than once, but it won't be inserted to the set because it will be there at that time. A set can only contain unique elements (2 strings with the same value can't exist in the same set).

Answer (score 4):

**SWIFT 5.1**

This has been answered, but I dare to come with a more simple solution.

If you take your array and convert it into a `Set` you will remove any duplicated items and end up with a set of unique items in no particular order since the nature of a `Set` is unordered.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set

If you then convert it back to an array and pick 5 elements you will end up with an array of random items.

But it's just 1 line ;)

Example:

```
var original = ["A","B","C","C","C","D","E","F","G","H"]
let random = Array(Set(original)).prefix(5)
```

Example print:

```
["B", "G", "H", "E", "C"]
```

The only requirement is your objects must conform to the Hashable protocol. Most standard Swift types do, otherwise, it's often simple to make your own types conform.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable

Comment: Nice idea, but the element are not random anymore this way.

Comment: They are? - I just tested this on the latest version and they are completely random for each run.

Comment: This will not change before the behavior of Sets change, which seems highly unlikely. Or what do you mean with it's not random "anymore"? :)

Comment: Hey @bjorn, sorry I misunderstood your answer initially. I think your idea is smart and your answer is simpler and much more better than mine! Thanks for adding it. I think it would be great if the OP chose it as the accepted answer. 

Answer (score 3):

[swift-algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/RandomSampling.md) now includes an extension to `Sequence` called `randomSample`.

```swift
import Algorithm

var array1 = ["salmon", "turkey", "salad", "curry", "sushi", "pizza"]
array1.randomSample(count: 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about changing the original array, the following code will put the picked elements at the end of the array and then it will return the last part of the array as a slice.
This is useful if you don't care about changing the original array, the advantage is that it doesn't use extra memory, and you can call it several times on the same array.

```
extension Array {
    mutating func takeRandomly(numberOfElements n: Int) -> ArraySlice<Element> {
        assert(n <= self.count)
        for i in stride(from: self.count - 1, to: self.count - n - 1, by: -1) {
            let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(i + 1)))
            self.swapAt(i, randomIndex)
        }
        return self.suffix(n)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4]
let a1 = array.takeRandomly(numberOfElements: 2)
let a2 = array.takeRandomly(numberOfElements: 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 = ["salmon", "turkey", "salad", "curry", "sushi", "pizza"]

while array1.count > 0 {

    // random key from array
    let arrayKey = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array1.count)))

    // your random number
    let randNum = array1[arrayKey] 

    // make sure the number ins't repeated
    array1.removeAtIndex(arrayKey)
}
```

By removing your picked value from array, prevent's from duplicates to be picked

Comment: Your Answer helps alot ty, but i cant seem to get it to work.


I end up with this

var array1 = ["salmon", "turkey", "salad", "curry", "sushi", "pizza"]

while array1.count > 0{
    
    // random key from array
    let arrayKey = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array1.count)))
    
    // your random number
    let randNum = array1[arrayKey]
    
    // make sure the number ins't repeated
    array1.removeAtIndex(arrayKey)
}

Comment: This solution can't handle the case when the array contains 2 elements with the same value, like this for example: ["salmon", "turkey", "salmon"].

Answer (score 0):

Just my ¢2:
[Moe Abdul-Hameed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4763963/moe-abdul-hameed)'s solution has one theoretical drawback: if you roll the same `randomIndex` in every iteration, the `while` loop will never exit. It's very unlike tho.

Another approach is to create mutable copy of original array and then exclude picked items:

```
var source = array1
var dest = [String]()
for _ in 1...5 {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(source.count)))
    dest.append(source[randomIndex])
    source.remove(at: randomIndex)
}

print(dest)
```

Comment: wow this solution is also amazing thank you. Is it possible to make each element its own Label in xcode?

so the app would display all 5 randomly selected meals as there own labels?

Comment: Of course, you can create UILabel in code (if I understood your question correctly), like so:

`    for _ in 1...5 {
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(source.count)))

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = source[randomIndex]
        // setup label as needed (font, colors, etc.)
        // add constraints (personally I use SnapKit for easy constraints setup) or set frame
        parentView.addSubview(label)

        source.remove(at: randomIndex)
    }
`

Comment: Damn, no code formatting (except inline) in comments :(

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but i sadly cannot get the code to work in an actual project. For line var source = array1 it says "Cannot use instance member 'array1' within property initializer, property initializer run before self is available.



and for for _ in 1...5 { it says "Expected declaration"

Comment: As compiler says, you are trying to execute the code inside of property initializer or even outside of any function. In first case self.array1 is not yet available, in second - it is semantic error. I suspect your case is the second, so you'll need to move the code into some function, e.g. viewDidLoad(). Please check out this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873673/swift-compiler-shows-expected-declaration-error