# Generate random Strings without a shuffle and repetition of previous ones?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, random

My code already generates a random String of an array when I press a button, but sometimes a String gets repeated. What do I have to do so that the String "Mango" only gets called again when all the other Strings where already called without using a shuffle, I want to call one String at a time?

Example: "Mango", "Kiwi", "Banana", "Pineapple", "Melon", "Mango", "Kiwi",.....

Here is my code:

```
var array = ["Mango", "Banana", "Apple","Kiwi", "Melon", "Pineapple"]

let fruits = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))

print(array[fruits])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Randomly select 5 elements from an array list without repeating an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132047/randomly-select-5-elements-from-an-array-list-without-repeating-an-element)

Comment: no, i already saw this. i don´t want to print the whole list with a shuffle. i want to call just one @lukvol

Comment: Why don't you want to use a shuffle?

Comment: Because it prints out all elements of the array, not just one @rmaddy

Comment: No, the shuffle does not print all the elements. Printing the shuffled array prints out all of the elements. Shuffle the array. Access the result one at a time. Done.

Comment: how can i do that @rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid repetitions you need to keep track of which fruits have previously been seen.  There are several ways to do that an all of the proposed solutions do it in one way or another.

For your specific use case, you will need this tracking to be retained outside of the code executed by the button (in your view controller for example).

Here is a generalized structure that could help with this:
(you can define it inside the view controller if this is a one-time thing or outside of it if you intend to reuse the mechanism elsewhere)

```
struct RandomItems
{
   var items : [String]
   var seen  = 0

   init(_ items:[String])
   { self.items = items }

   mutating func next() -> String
   {
     let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(items.count - seen)))
     let item  = items.remove(at:index)
     items.append(item)
     seen = (seen + 1) % items.count
     return item
   }
}
```

To use it, you would declare a variable (in your VC) that will keep track of your fruits:

```
var fruits = RandomItems(["Mango", "Banana", "Apple","Kiwi", "Melon", "Pineapple"])
```

And in the button's code use that variable (fruits) to print a non-repeating fruit name at each execution

```
func buttonPressed() // <- use your function here
{
    print( fruits.next() )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement some logic. It's quite easy if you think harder. Run this in your Playground, or if you fully understand this block of code, you can do this in your project already.

```
var array = ["Mango", "Banana", "Apple","Kiwi", "Melon", "Pineapple"]
var selectedIndices = [Int]()

for _ in 1...20 {

    let randomFruitIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))

    // Print only if not yet printed once

    if !selectedIndices.contains(randomFruitIndex) {
        print(array[randomFruitIndex])
        selectedIndices.append(randomFruitIndex)
    }

    // Reset

    if selectedIndices.count == array.count {
        print("----- CLEARING SELECTED INDICES----")
        selectedIndices.removeAll()
    }
}
```

So as you can see, we are adding each generated random number (in your case, it's the `fruits` variable.) into an array of `Int`. Then if the number of `selectedIndices` is equal to the count of the `array` of fruits, clear all the stored `selectedIndices`.

OUTPUT:

```
Pineapple
Melon
Mango
Kiwi
Banana
Apple
----- CLEARING SELECTED INDICES----
Mango
Melon
```

Comment: The OUTPUT should look like:  Mango //And if the user clicks on the button the next fruit get called @Glenn

Answer (score 0):

This is an adaption from the accepted answer of the linked topic in my comment:

```
var source = ["Mango", "Banana", "Apple","Kiwi", "Melon", "Pineapple"]
var usedElements = [String]()

func choosePseudoRandomElement() -> String {
    if source.count == 0 {
        source = usedElements
        usedElements = []
    }

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(source.count)))
    let randomItem = source[randomIndex]
    usedElements.append(randomItem)
    source.remove(at: randomIndex)

    return randomItem
}

for _ in 1...18 {
    print("Item: \(choosePseudoRandomElement())")
}
```

One potential issue with this solution is that it may happen, that the last element of one complete iteration also occurs as the first element of the second iteration. You can handle that case by comparing the randomly chosen item with the item which was chosen before (use a while loop until the items doesn't match anymore).
Also, this does remove elements from the source array. If you do not want that, create a copy of the source array.

Comment: Now I get 18 fruits printed out I, it should be just one @lukvol

Comment: You can ignore the for-loop at the end. Just call the choosePseudoRandomElement and print the result whenever you need another element.

Comment: how can i call the result @lukvol