# How can I do a random String array without repeating in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, pickerview

I am working on picker views and I am doing a trivia game. So I got an Array with different questions and another one with answers, this is what I have:

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdS9S.png)

So my question is: I need to do this but without repeating questions/answers, is there some solution?

I thought in doing two arrays, one for questions and another one with those questions but randomized, because when people answer I have to delete the question just so it doesn't repeat. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can have a separate array that holds questions already asked. Then before you pick a question you can check to make sure it hasn’t already been asked.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382227/generate-random-strings-without-a-shuffle-and-repetition-of-previous-ones, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132047/randomly-select-5-elements-from-an-array-list-without-repeating-an-element, and of course https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift.