# Simple problem that using method in ViewController

Tags: swift

```
class MemoListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .long
```

I write formatter code under ViewController but it doesn't work..

```
let formatter: DateFormatter = {
    let f = DateFormatter()
    f.dateStyle = .long
    return f
}()
```

But I wirte code using closure and it works!

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
```

And i wirte code same as first code in tableView function. And it works.

I don't understand why first code isn't work..

Let me know what I need to learn.. thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by not work? What errors come?

Comment: Where you write this line : formatter.dateStyle = .long ? you have to write this inside the viewDidLoad()

Comment: Define doesn't work? For the first one, it's written "like that", Put anywhere in the code? You can't do that. The second one should be better, but where is it written?

Comment: You cant edit the variable formatter outside of a function.

Comment: I solve this problem..  thank you everyone! 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873673/swift-compiler-shows-expected-declaration-error?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing your code without any kind of scope, you need to place your formatter code in a function within your controller.

```
class MemoListTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .long
    }
    func myFunction() {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .long
    }
}
```